# C# - Progress bar wont display value

Tags: c#, progress-bar

In my application I need a progress bar to display the progress of a plant growing. This would be the code:

```
    private static Timer farmProgress;
    internal void initFarmProgTimer( int step, int max = 100 )
    {
        farmProgress = new Timer();
        farmProgress.Tick += new EventHandler(farmProgress_Tick);
        farmProgress.Interval = step; // in miliseconds
        farmProgress.Start();



    }
    private void farmProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (increment >= 100)
        {
            // wait till user get plant
        }
        else
        {
            increment++;
            plantProgressBar.Value = increment;
        }
    }
```

Here the call of the `initFarmProgTimer` function:

```
    public static System.Threading.Timer growTimer;
    public static void InitGrowTimer(int time, string name)
    {
        growTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(growTimer_Finished, null, time, Timeout.Infinite);
        plantActive = true;

        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.initFarmProgTimer(time / 100);
    }
```

Note that the class where this function is called from is NOT a form but the class where the function is defined IS a form.

Does anybody know what my error is?

**edit**
here is the call for the InitGrowTimer function

```
    switch ( index )
        {
            case 0:
                currentPlant = wheat.name;
                plantQ = printPlantDatas("wheat");
                if (plantQ == true)
                {
                    InitGrowTimer(wheat.time, wheat.name);
                    wheat.planted++;
                }
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Why is the farmProgress Timer static? Each time you call "initFarmProgTimer" on different instances of the Menu class, you override the timer.

Comment: @Dietz I removed the `static` tag. It still doesnt work, I think there is a problem with accessing the progressBar.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the "farmProgress_Tick" callback, can you confirm that "plantProgressBar.Value" is incremented as expected ?

Comment: @Dietz I already tried that and yes, both `increment` and `plantProgressBar.Value` are increased. Maybe because I created a new Instance of Menu and now it is not running correctly?

Comment: Maybe the "farmProgress_Tick" runs in a background thread, and you need to invoke it to the UI thread ?

Comment: @Dietz What would that change? I mean the value gets increased but it is not displayed, thats my main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value to the progress bar which will only set the progress to the current value. You have to increment it  rather. I have added the pluss (+) sign for you

```
 private void farmProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (increment >= 100)
        {
            // wait till user get plant
        }
        else
        {
            increment++;
            plantProgressBar.Value += increment;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That cant be the problem. The increment is being increased by 1 every time before the `.Value = ` part. The progressBar simply doesnt react to ANY values I want to assign during code.

Comment: I can't even see the increment declaration. Where does it gets it value

Comment: Directly before the Timer defenition.
`private int increment = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what is on a Form and what isn't but assuming this is on the Form:

```
    private void farmProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (increment >= 100)
        {
            // wait till user get plant
        }
        else
        {
            increment++;
            plantProgressBar.Value = increment;
        }
    }
```

Change it to this so that you update the control from the UI thread:

```
    private void farmProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (increment >= 100)
        {
            // wait till user get plant
        }
        else
        {
            increment++;                
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                       plantProgressBar.Value = increment;
               }));
        }
    }
```

> Update

My answer is wrong, I didn't expect this, but I created a Forms application and this worked fine to increment the progressbar:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer farmProgress;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        farmProgress = new Timer();
        farmProgress.Tick += farmProgress_Tick;
        farmProgress.Interval = 1000; // in miliseconds
        farmProgress.Start();
    }

    void farmProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried this and got this Exception: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll`. What is going on?

Comment: @IanH.not sure what is going on. What is the complete exception msg?

Comment: that was the complete exception message. The title was: `InvalidOperationException was unhandled`

Comment: Tried, worked. But it doesnt work with my method by calling it from another class. Maybe it creates a new instance but the normal menu is on another?

Comment: Like I said, it's not clear to me what is the Form and what is the other class. Typically I would expose /raise events in the class and subscribe to it on the Form rather than accessing a Form control from another object.